# Splitting a string in Java using multiple delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like

```
String myString = "hello world~~hello~~world"
```

I am using the split method like this

```
String[] temp = myString.split("~|~~|~~~");
```

I want the array temp to contain only the strings separated by ~, ~~ or ~~~.

However, the temp array thus created has length 5, the 2 additional 'strings' being empty strings.

I want it to ONLY contain my non-empty string. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Please format your code with the corresponding markup for readability: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Sorry, I will pay attention :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use quantifier with your character:

```
String[] temp = myString.split("~+");
```

[`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regex. `~+` will match 1 or more `~`, so it will split on `~`, or `~~`, or `~~~`, and so on.

Also, if you just want to split on `~`, `~~`, or `~~~`, then you can limit the repetition by using `{m,n}` quantifier, which matches a pattern from *m* to *n* times:

```
String[] temp = myString.split("~{1,3}");
```

---

When you split it the way you are doing, it will split `a~~b` twice on `~`, and thus the middle element will be an empty string.

You could also have solved the problem by reversing the order of your delimiter like this:

```
String[] temp = myString.split("~~~|~~|~");
```

That will first try to split on `~~`, before splitting on `~` and will work fine. But you should use the first approach.

Comment: @Betlista `+` is a regex quantifier which means match the precedent token 1 or *more* times. Which means it will also cover `~~~~~~~~~~~` :-)

Comment: I know exactly what is the meaning of `+`, but he is asking to "...contain only the strings separated by ~, ~~ or ~~~.", so maybe `"~{1,3}"` is better

Comment: @Betlista. Hmm. may be you are right. I'll add a not of it in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just turn the pattern around:

```
    String myString = "hello world~~hello~~world";
    String[] temp = myString.split("~~~|~~|~");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This :

```
myString.split("~~~|~~|~");
```

It will definitely works. In your code, what actually happens that when `~` occurs for the first time,it count as a first separator and split the string from that point. So it doesn't get `~~` or `~~~` anywhere in your string though it is there. Like :

```
[hello world]~[]~[hello]~[]~[world]
```

Square brackets are split-ed in to 5 different string values.